# Combining 2 boxplots to 1

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

Below is the data for scatterplot:

```
Length A B
250  -25 30
400  100 40
100   19 60
120   -3 50
300    7 90
```

I would like to make a single boxplot for each model A and B and plot their values. Also, I would like to color the point "red" with Length>=250. Below is the code which produces 2 random boxplots for each model.

```
scattertest %>%
    pivot_longer(cols=-length,names_to="Model",values_to="Delta") %>%
    ggplot(aes(x=Model, y=Delta, color=ifelse(Length>=250,"black","red"))) +
    geom_boxplot() + geom_jitter() + scale_color_identity()
```

[image: Boxplot]

Answer (score 1):

Change location of color

```
    scattertest %>%
      pivot_longer(cols=-Length,names_to="Model",values_to="Delta") %>%
      ggplot(aes(x=Model, y=Delta)) +
      geom_boxplot() + geom_jitter(aes( color=ifelse( Length >=250,"black","red"))) + scale_color_identity()
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick solution. It worked great!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to let `ggplot2` know how to group your data back into one boxplot.  I say "back" into one boxplot, since setting the `color` aesthetic within `aes()` causes `ggplot` to group according to that color statement, then apply the color to those filtered layers.  You can maintain the `aes()`, but get back your intended grouping by specifying the `group=` aesthetic:

```
scattertest %>%
  pivot_longer(cols=-length,names_to="Model",values_to="Delta") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Model, y=Delta, color=ifelse(length>=250,"black","red"))) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(group=Model)) + geom_jitter() + scale_color_identity()
```

[image]

Alternatively, change the location of the `color=` aesthetic to be inside your `geom_jitter()` call as mentioned by @Park.  If you set the aesthetic within `ggplot()` it's applied to all geoms.  If you set the aesthetic in a single geom, it will only apply to that geom.

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt and detailed solution. It worked perfect :)